# ssl offloader for websockets

Tags: ssl, nginx, haproxy, socket

im looking for a proxy which supports a massive load (like nginx or [haproxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/)) and can handle websockets and ssl. i know only nginx which does not support websockets and haproxy which doesnt support ssl offloading.

thanks

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: its nearly non-existent at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a number of tutorials using stunnel to decrypt the SSL traffic then pass the unencrypted traffic on to haproxy, and finally the web server. I am not aware of its performance limitations however.

Answer (score 0):

I have been putting Apache httpd in front of haproxy to handle the SSL traffic.  Apache runs on port 443 and handles the SSL traffic on the front end and then uses the proxy module to forward the traffic to a haproxy instance that is listening to a high port number on 127.0.0.1.  haproxy then forwards the traffic to the backend servers.

Comment: thanks. i think apache is not able to handle such a high load. i'm required to handle really many connections.

Comment: How about putting pound in front of it?